How to say that two different functions apply the same rule?
I need to find a way to formally say that two different functions apply the same rule. Let me provide an example of what I mean.
Let $X=\{1,2,3\}$ and $Y=\{4,5,6,7\}$. Then, let $f:X\to\{2,4,6\}$ and $g:Y\to\{8,10,12,14\}$ be two functions satisfying $f(x)=2x$ for all $x\in X$ and $g(y)=2y$ for all $y\in Y$. Then, it is obvious that $f$ and $g$ are different functions, since they have different domains, codomains and images.
However, both $f$ and $g$ apply the same operation to the elements of their respective domains: namely, they both multiply by 2 each element in their domains. Hence, I feel there is a sense in which the functions $f$ and $g$ are similar. It is almost like there exists some sort of morphism between the two.
I am looking for a formal way to say that two different functions apply the same rule or law, despite having different domains, codomains and images.
How to formalise the notion that two different functions apply the same rule?

Potentially relevant https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2751540/if-two-functions-are-defined-by-the-same-formula-but-have-different-codomains

How do you know that $f$ applies that doubling rule and not, say, the rule "add 2, square it, divide by 4, round down"?

@jonnybolton16 Thank you for your comment—the link you posted was indeed useful.

@MarkS. I guess I do not? I am somewhat confused, because I thought that a function is completely defined by its domain, codomain and image. But as you point out, two functions performing different operations can share the same domain, codomain and image; and thus be the same function…

"Function" as used in math is completely determined by the codomain and the input-output pairs. But there are many calculations that could lead to those pairs, so if you want to confirm that two calculations are doing the same sort of steps, the standard mathematical definition of function doesn't capture that. You'd  have to say something along the lines of "these two functions use the same programming code" which would be more structure than the concept of "function" (to say nothing of uncomputable functions).

@MarkS. Thank you very much for your comment. I am not facing a programming problem, but an applied math one in social choice theory. So, let me ask you: is there any mathematical object that captures the notions of both a function plus the operation it performs? Suppose that my functions map from square matrices of dimension $t$ to vectors of dimension $t$.

Without a very strong restriction like maybe "the only operations allowed are linear transformations", the only such formalizations I'm aware of amount to things as strong as formalization of programming itself, since the theoretical versions of programming represent all "operations" one might perform. I'd recommend you give the full context in a brand new question, but am pessimistic that the answer you seek lies in mathematics if the real restriction is, say, "a calculation a human can do in their head".

Let $Z=X \cup Y$
Let $h:Z \to \{\cdots\}$
We can then use the terminology that $f$ & $g$ are restrictions of the same function $h$
[[ In other words , $f$ is similar to $h$ , $g$ is similar to $h$ , hence $f$ is similar to $g$ too ]]
Direction can change : $h$ is the [[ common ]] extension of $f$ & $g$ , indicating sameness
More here :
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Restriction_(mathematics)

Thank you for your answer. I have accepted it because it solves the problem I posted. Unfortunately, it does not solve the problem I do really have. But that’s entirely my fault, because I posted a simplified version of my problem that does not really capture it correctly. I guess I’ll have to post a different question later.

Oh okay. When you do decide to make a new Post , ideally you should comment it somewhere here.

Please, feel free to see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4942442/how-to-ensure-that-a-voting-rule-that-deals-with-alternative-sets-of-different-s.
